# Accessing message queue on a virtual machine

Tags: c#-4.0, .net-4.0, msmq

Does anybody know how can I access a private queue on a virtual machine?
I am using c# .Net 4. I tried using MyQueue= new MessageQueue(@"MachineName\Private$\queuename); and used the ip address for the MachineName in order to connect but I get an error saying "invalid queue path name"
Could that be because the machine needs a username and password? If so how can I pass it to the machine?

Any help is appreciated.
Best,
Mariann

Answer (score 0):

Try to use format name like 
DIRECT=OS:YOURMACHINENAME\private$\YourQueueName